# nodejs setTimeout memory leak?

Tags: node.js, memory

v0.10.4

Here's the simple loop that results in an ever-increasing memory usage:

```
function redx(){
      setTimeout(function(){ redx() },1000);
      console.log('loop');
}

redx();
```

What am I doing wrong ??

## EDIT

OK, just tried the suggestion to reference the timeout object in the scope and it seems that garbage collection does kick in after about 40 seconds, here's abbreviated logs from TOP:

3941 root      20   0   32944   7284   4084 S 4.587 3.406   0:01.32 node
 3941 root      20   0   32944   7460   4084 S 2.948 3.489   0:01.59 node
 3941 root      20   0   32944   7516   4084 S 2.948 3.515   0:01.68 node
 3941 root      20   0   33968   8400   4112 S 2.948 3.928   0:02.15 node
 3941 root      20   0   33968   8920   4112 S 3.275 4.171   0:02.98 node
 3941 root      20   0   33968   8964   4112 S 2.948 4.192   0:03.07 node
 3941 root      20   0   33968   9212   4112 S 2.953 4.308   0:03.16 node
 3941 root      20   0   33968   9212   4112 S 2.953 4.308   0:03.25 node
 3941 root      20   0   33968   9212   4112 S 3.276 4.308   0:03.35 node
 3941 root      20   0   33968   9212   4112 S 2.950 4.308   0:03.44 node

Comment: Incredible, I had been wondering that myself yesterday. My guess is that Node does not collect the closures of the anonymous function.

Comment: What operating system are you working on?

Comment: I'm testing this under ARCH.

Answer (score 5):

No idea why but apparently if you reference the timeout object in the scope of the function nodejs will do the garbage collect that correctly.

```
function redx(){
      var t = setTimeout(function(){ redx() },50);
      console.log('hi');
}

redx();
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tested your code and unfortunately for me it does not solve the issue and I don't see any noticeable difference in the memory consumption.

Comment: Correction, I just looked at this again and memory usage does keep increasing initially and then peaks out after about 40 seconds !

Comment: weird, i can clearly see memory usage increase and then getting back to initial value (i guess thats when gc kicks in)

Comment: quasi-realtime commenting system issues. please flip the order of comments #3 and #2 ;)

Comment: @crankshaft can you confirm that really worked and accept answer if so?

Comment: I have a memory leaking probably caused by setTimeout as well. Just to difficult to spot it. I'm using node-memwatch and just pushed the code with change. So far, leaks are not detected. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I think it might be just the way the V8 garbage collector works.

On my system, node heap tends to increase up to 48 MB and then stabilize, so I think if you keep your program running for a long time, the memory consumption will eventually stabilize.

You can have information about when/how the GC kicks in by launching node with one of the V8 command line option: the --trace_gc flag.

In your first tries with Redis, you were systematically connecting/disconnecting from Redis at each call. This tends to generate garbage. You are supposed to open a connection once and use it many times. Nevertheless, even when I do this, memory consumption tends to stabilize. Here is the evolution of memory consumption on this example with Redis:

```
// something close to your initial function (when Redis was still in the picture)
function redx(){
    var client = redis.createClient();
    client.get("tally", function(err, reply) {
        client.quit();
    });
    setTimeout(function(){ redx() }, 50 );
}
```

[image: Evolution of memory consumption with Redis connect/disconnect]

Here, the stabilization after 60 MB seems to be quite obvious.

Comment: Thanks, yes originaly I thought this was a problem with redis / memcache but after stripping the code to a bare minimum, i found that just the setTimeout was resulting in this leak. Th reason I kept opening a new connection, is that this may run for many months and I was unsure if holding open a localhost connection for that amount of time would be reliable.

Comment: I can confirm the above graph. Nodejs seems to stabilize its memory consumption after a while. This is very typical in most GCs. I even had the same results by generating an isolated scope that was calling `redx()` in a setTimeout loop. I also had the same graph by calling `setTimeout(redx.bind(null), 50);` . I have a guess in the example above, `var client = ...` is getting unreachable after next loops so it gets Garbage collected after a while, and so memory leak shouldn't also apply. it might generate Mem Leak to Redis but this is off discussion.