# Perform long-polling from nodejs (possible memory leak)

Tags: facebook, node.js

I wrote a piece of code that is going to perform a request to Facebook.

Now i wrapped this code into a infinite loop which is going to send those requests every 10 seconds using timeouts.

Code:

```
var poll = function(socket, userProvider) {    
    var lastCallTime = new Date();
    var polling = true;

    // The stream itself, non blocking
    function performPoll() {
        var results = feed(function (err, data) {
            lastCallTime = new Date();

            // PROCESS DATA

            // Check new posts
            if (polling) {
                setTimeout(performPoll, 1000 * 10);
            }
        });  
    };

    // Start infinite loop
    performPoll();
};
```

The feed(cb) is just going to call a request to Facebook requesting data, this works 100% and does what i want it to do, the only problem that i am having now is that this piece of code is keeping to increase my memory usage. After a few minutes it increased by 50MB already (From 50 -> 100).

Is there anybody that can help me identify the cause of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v8 does not collect memory immediately. If it stabilizes at 100mb, then it is to be expected. For more information, checkout [nodejs setTimeout memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072699/nodejs-settimeout-memory-leak)

If you really, really want to clear the memory, use global.gc(). Read [this blog](http://simonmcmanus.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/forcing-garbage-collection-with-node-js-and-v8/) about how to call garbage collector manually.

Comment: I tried what you said, i kept it running for a few hours and it still keeps increasing, it is at 116Mb now and rising. 

I tested the loop separately and then the problem does not occur, i can see the problem occurring when i start doing the http requests (Which just uses the request library that you can find in npm)

Comment: Ok found it, i was apparently doing some UDP connections without closing them somewhere in my code and that opened file descriptors, that made my app to crash. Now i removed those and the memory is getting cleaned by GC like it should be cleaned :) thank you for your response since you were right :)